# How does angularJs keep filter so that it is still enable when history back

Tags: angularjs

Just like the example of angularJs: http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-12/app/#/phones, the filter could not be kept in angularJs, so after getting filter results, and then click one of the mobile to see the detail, and then click back of browser, the filter will disappear. I am wondering about if there is any way we could use to keep the filter?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Zhang, but seems it is a jQuery way. I've found the solution using angularJs. Simply put, store the filter in $rootScope when you type the search string, and then set it back when loading the view. See codes below:

```
// controller
function xxxController($rootScope, $scope) {
    //set saved search string back to model
    $scope.SearchModel = $rootScope.searchString;

    $scope.saveSearchString() = function() {
        $rootScope.searchString = $scope.SearchModel;
    }
// view
<input type="text" ng-change="saveSearchString()" ng-model="SearchModel">
```

Maybe you want to clear the saved search string when clicking some link, you could reset $rootScope.searchString to empty. e.g.

```
// another controller
function otherController($rootScope, $scope) {
    $scope.resetContext = function() {
        $rootScope.searchString = "";
    }
}
// view
<a href="/data" ng-click="resetContext()">clickme</a>
```

Hope helpful to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You can temp the search field value:

```
var sTemp =$('#search').val();
```

and when you back:

```
if(!sTemp){
  $('#search').val(sTemp);
  $('#search').trigger('change');
}
```

Not tested it, just a approaching to achieve this